# Netbeans Preview GUI Not Matching Run

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I'm experimenting with Java (Swing) GUIs and have encountered an odd issue using Netbeans 8.2.  I jump between two computers (one Win7 and the other Win10) and made several modifications on the application on the Win7 machine.  When I moved the application back to my Win10 machine, the preview shows the old interface while the run command shows the now modified interface.

I've seen several posts talking about refreshing the GUI (both manually and automatically) and have deleted the cache multiple time from \AppData\Local\Netbeans...  I've also tried clean build and open/close the project.

Anyone else have any suggestions on what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure you copied all the files back  including '.form' files?

Comment: @ WillShackleford Yes, I was coping the entire source folder including the .form file

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but I ended up deleting the entire folder structure from the Win10 machine and copied the Win7 folder to a new location.  It seems to be working now.